Issues with displaying the graph generated using table in outlook
I'm using the following code to generate a graph where the widths are calculated dynamically based on current and projected values, both of which are also dynamic. While the graph displays correctly in an online HTML compiler, it does not render properly in Outlook. Please help me resolve this issue.
<table style="background-color: #343a42; border-radius: 10px; padding: 15px;" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr style="width: 100%;">
            <td style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 12px; padding-left: 16px; padding-bottom: 4px; width: 70%;">Measurement in Gigabytes (GB)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="width: 100%; display: flex;">
            <td style="font-size: 12px; width: auto; writing-mode: vertical-rl; float: left; color: #fff; text-align: center;">AT&T</td>
            <td style="width: 100%;">
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
                            <td
                                style="
                                    color: #fbfcfd;
                                    font-size: 12px;
                                    padding-top: 10px;
                                    height: 65px;
                                    padding: 13px 0;
                                    border-radius: 0px 0 0 0px;
                                    z-index: 9;
                                    opacity: 0.75;
                                    background-color: #2b6a88;
                                    display: flex;
                                    justify-content: flex-end;
                                    align-items: center;
                                    padding-right: 8px;
                                    width: 68%;
                                    position: absolute;
                                "
                            >
                                8339.75
                            </td>
                            <td style="background-color: #90ee9080; width: 100%; padding: 10px; height: 50px; color: #fff; left: 0; top: 13px; align-items: center; display: flex; justify-content: flex-end; opacity: 0.75;">12227.25</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="margin-left: 16px; width: 100%; display: flex;">
            <td style="color: #fbfcfd; font-size: 12px; padding-top: 4px; width: 100%;">Current</td>
            <td style="color: #fbfcfd; font-size: 12px; text-align: end; padding-top: 4px; width: 100%;">Projected</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

        Measurement in Gigabytes (GB)
    
    
        A
        
            
                
                    
                        <td
                            style="
                                color: #fbfcfd;
                                font-size: 12px;
                                padding-top: 10px;
                                height: 65px;
                                padding: 13px 0;
                                border-radius: 0px 0 0 0px;
                                z-index: 9;
                                opacity: 0.75;
                                background-color: #2b6a88;
                                display: flex;
                                justify-content: flex-end;
                                align-items: center;
                                padding-right: 8px;
                                width: 68%;
                                position: absolute;
                            "
                        >
                            8339.75
                        
                        12221.25
                    
                
            
        
    
    
        Current
        Projected

the graph generated in the online html compiler is first image  enter image description here and second image is generated in outlook enter image description hereenter image description here ,

The CSS that is supported in Outlook varies on different operating systems. You can check at https://www.caniemail.com/ For example, flex isn't supported on Windows currently.
